# Why did Sinestro put on the yellow ring at the end of the Green Lantern movie?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the *Green Lantern* movie, there was an after-credit scene which displayed that Sinestro put on the yellow ring of fear.

Sinestro wasn't a dumb guy. He was one of the smartest Lanterns in the universe. And, he knew that even a Guardian was unable to control power of fear. Power of fear was unpredictable unlike power of Will.

Initially, [he agreed to master power of fear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/why-did-sinestro-think-that-forging-a-yellow-ring-was-a-good-idea) because there wasn't another way in front of him to beat Parallax. But, why did he try it at the end, when Parallax had already been defeated by Hal Jordan (who showed that Will was more powerful than Fear)?

Comment: To set up for the sequel.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the character of Sinestro in the movie is the same as his characterization in the comic, then his rationale for taking and believing he could master the yellow ring is simple.

- He is as arrogant as he is intelligent. His experience both as a leader, trainer and operative of the Green Lantern Corps has created the impression in his mind, if nowhere else, he is able to do something even the Guardians couldn't do.
- He truly believes he is the best Green Lantern to have ever lived and has become emotionally compromised to the point of believing he could use and master the Yellow power and its attendant flaw.
- In the comics, Sinestro uses the Yellow Power longer than any other ring-wielder and has greater facility and experience in mastering his personal fears.

Comment: Willpower leads to arrogance, arrogance leads to anger, anger leads to hatred, hatred leads to fear and fear leads to the Yellow Ring.

Comment: He also has lost confidence that Guardians have the will to do what is necessary - he may have doubts about the ring, but he sees it as the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine because he has always believed himself the superior green lantern... but when he saw this rookie, Hal Jordan, defeat Parallax where he and his best lanterns couldn't, he realized he was outmatched as a green lantern. My guess is he took the yellow ring because it would put him in a class all his own. Plus he still had his green ring, so there is a chance he thought he could master both yellow and green at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I think sinestro wanted to outrank all green lanterns by believing the yellow power ring was the strongest ring because of its power of fear

Comment: Source for that?

Comment: He's Sinestro, thats first hand experience right there.